# How to get rasa training time

Tags: rasa

I have a script that uses rasa trainer from “rasa.nlu.model.Trainer” to train rasa model. This script is called using a REST-API. When the user calls this api, the model starts training, but I want to give the user a estimation about the training time or show the progress bar percentage for him/her. How can I get this training duration or any callback about the training progress? any idea?